# VS2015 unable to open performance driver, access denied

Tags: visual-studio-2015, profiling, windows-10, instrumentation

I am trying to run instrumentation profiling for a C++ application through VS2015 on Windows 10, but it fails with this warning:

```
Warning VSP2347: The monitor was unable to open the VS performance driver.  Access is denied. Consider using the /Admin:Security option of VSPerfCmd from an elevated environment.  Performance counter data and detection of kernel mode execution is disabled.
```

I am using an Administrator account and have already followed the instructions listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182387.aspx) using an Admin command console.

I have verified that the profiling service manager and kernel mode drivers are installed and running:

```
vsperfcmd /admin:security,list
Microsoft (R) VSPerf Command Version 14.0.23107 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

security,list
VSPerfSrv Profiling Service Manager Status:
VSPerfSrv is installed and running.
VSPerfDrv Kernel Mode Driver Status:
VSPerfDrv140 is installed and running.
Authorized Profiler Users:
  BUILTIN\Administrators Allowed: FullAccess
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed: FullAccess
```

I restarted Visual Studio after running the vsperfcmd commands just in case, but I still get the same error. Any searches online mention special concerns dealing with Windows 8, but nothing related to 10. Is there any way to get this running?

Comment: have you tried completely cleaning the compile directory? or running clean solution?

Comment: Just tried that, but it did not make a difference

Comment: Looks like you are hitting [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/profiler/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8/) limitation which exists starting from Windows 8, i.e. on Windows 10 as well.

Comment: What was that limitation? That link is dead now.